# How can i add new database connection details to my spring basicdatasource after run time?

Tags: java, spring

at run time user give some databse details like IP, username, password.
How Spring will connect to this database without restarting the server.

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507522/dynamically-change-spring-data-source

Comment: In your above answer there is ony two databse major or minor but in my case i dont know which database IP,username and password user will give.

Answer (score 0):

Get the datasource bean programatically after user input and set the values.

```
BasicDataSource newDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
newDataSource.setDriverClassName(request.getParameter("driverClassName"));
newDataSource.setUrl(request.getParameter("url"));
newDataSource.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
newDataSource.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
```

Also you can try using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555611/changing-datasource-connection-url-runtime)

Comment: Your answer sounds good. but In my project i have two basicdatasource server and client. So Give some example link  how can i connect through programmetically setting up users details about database.

Comment: In your above examplethere is only three databse major or minor but in my case i dont know which database IP,username and password user will give. –